# how to set a cookie for a rhomobile/rhodes webview

Tags: ruby, cookies, webview, rhodes

i am using a rhomobile/rhodes app to talk to a web service and display content in a WebView, when i send the login information in a Rho::AsyncHttp.post with the login details and a callback i can see a successful login on the web service and the application gets a cookie that i can puts and view.  so far so good.

however, the next thing i try is to use that cookie to authenticate the WebView, so in the callback:

```
WebView.set_cookie("10.0.1.190", @params['cookies'])
WebView.navigate("10.0.1.190")
```

but this redirects me to the login page.  the cookie that is sent does not match the cookie in `@params['cookies']`, is there a different way to set cookies for ip addresses?  or am i doing something wrong, or is this broken in rhodes at the moment?  i tried 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 for both android and iphone and they had the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out WebView.set_cookie doesn't currently work for 3.0.1, but you can set the cookie in javascript... this is the hack i wound up with that seems to work:

```
def login
  WebView.navigate("http://www.mysite.com/blank.html")
  Rho::AsyncHttp.post(
    :url => "http://www.mysite.com/login?user[username]=joeblow&user[password]=supersecret",
    :callback => url_for(:action => :login_callback)
  )
  render :action => :wait
end

def login_callback
  WebView.execute_js("document.cookie='#{@params["cookies"]};expires=Fri, June 10 12:00:00 UTC;path=/;domain=.mysite.com'")
  WebView.navigate("http://www.mysite.com")
end
```

blank.html is just an empty file to get the WebView loaded without setting any cookies.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me without using js. I think it was probably because I was adding multiple cookies, so I ended up adding them one by one instead of all of them at once in the callback.

```
  def login
      WebView.navigate("http://www.mysite.com/blank.html")
      Rho::AsyncHttp.post(
        :url => "http://www.mysite.com/login?user[username]=joeblow&user[password]=supersecret",
        :callback => url_for(:action => :login_callback)
      )
      render :action => :wait
    end



    def login_callback

        cookies = @params["cookies"].split(';');

            cookie_str = ""
                cookies.each do |c|
                    c = c + ';'
                    WebView.set_cookie("10.0.1.190", c)
                end
         WebView.navigate("http://www.mysite.com")

    end
```